# Why does `LogisticRegression` take target variable of type `object` without any error?

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, sklearn-pandas, multiclass-classification

Am using basic `LogisticRegression` on data for which the target variable is `multiclass`.

I was expecting `LogisticRegression` to give some error when the `fit()` was called. But it didnt.

Does `LogisticRegression` handle such case by default? If yes, what transformations are applied to the target variable?

```py
ddf = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1,2,3,4, "Blue"],
    [4,2,3,4, "Red"],
    [5,2,8,4, "Red"],
    [2,7,3,9, "Green"],
    [7,6,7,4, "Blue"]], columns=['A','B','C','D','E']
)
ddf
X = ddf[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
y = ddf['E']
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X, y)
preds = lr.predict(X)
print(preds)
```

Gives the output: `['Blue' 'Red' 'Red' 'Green' 'Blue']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scikit-learn is able to handle string labels for all the classifiers by default, internally it creates a [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) object, have a look at the code [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f6924/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py#L872). String-class labels are encoded to integer values.